# getting the largest value from a hash that is the value of another hash?

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I have a hash whose keys are datetimes, and whose values are hashes, like the following:

```
{datetime =>{"string0"=>int0, "string1"=>int1}}
```

Every value in the parent hash is of the same format - the same 2 strings as keys, with ints as values.  How would I find the largest `int0` in the entire hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash = {:foo =>{"string0"=>1, "string1"=>2}, :bar => {"string0"=>3, "string1"=>4}}
Hash[*hash.max_by { |_k, v| v['string0'] }]
#=> {:bar=>{"string0"=>3, "string1"=>4}}
```

To get the actual value:

```
hash.map { |_k, v| v['string0'] }.max
#=> 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this returns the full record though, I'm actually looking just for the value, not the entire record.

Comment: Thank you!  Will accept as soon as the required time has passed.

Comment: Andrey you're a machine. I'm still in irb to try out and you have already answered :D

Comment: @Ursus this is what I usually think about guys like [ndn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2423164/ndn), or [spickermann](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2483313/spickermann) when open a question and try to answer it :D By the time I come back from irb there's already few answers

Comment: Everybody is someone else's idol :P

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {:foo =>{"string0"=>1, "string1"=>2},
     :bar => {"string0"=>3, "string1"=>4, "string5"=>1} }

h.values.flat_map { |g| g.values_at("string0") }.max
  #=> 3
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = h.values
  #=> [{"string0"=>1, "string1"=>2}, {"string0"=>3, "string1"=>4, "string5"=>1}]
b = a.flat_map { |g| g.values_at("string0") }
  #=> [1, 3] 
b.max
  #=> 3
```

Comment: Nice one. `h.values.flat_map(&:values).max` is a bit shorter. And yea, it doesn't really return what OP wants, but definitely worth showing it!

Comment: Thanks, @Andrey. I'm getting a bit senile in my old age. Whenever one sees `flatten` a light bulb should go on: "Could I use `flat_map`?".

Comment: yea, "light bulb" is exactly what I have immediately when I see `flatten` :)